# NestedValueProvider issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

i'm trying to use **NestedValueProvider** like the example provided by Google cloud platform documentation https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates but it throws the exception : *unable to serialize NestedValueProvider{value=RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=date, default=null}, translator=}*

```
@Description("Processing date")
@Validation.Required
ValueProvider<String> getDate();
void setDate(ValueProvider<String> date);

PCollectionTuple lines = this.p
                    .apply("ReadW2", TextIO.read().from(ValueProvider.NestedValueProvider.of(options.getDate(), new SerializableFunction<String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String apply(String date) {
                            return "gs://bucketname/" + date;
                        }
                    })))
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it work for me, but i don't understand why.
I have just transformed my anonymous class into lambda expression.

```
PCollectionTuple lines = this.p
                    .apply("ReadW2", TextIO.read().from(NestedValueProvider.of(options.getDate(), (SerializableFunction<String, String>) date -> gs://bucketname/" + date)))
```